# dynamically bind a property to a class on the fly

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I want to dynamically create a typescript class and add assign a property to it on the fly.

the property may be a function or Promise or any other type and uses `this` and I want `this` inside it to refer to the class.

```
let MyClass = class{
  public property: any;
  public ok = 1;
}


let property = function(){ console.log(this.ok); }

// now we want `this` to refer to MyClass instead of its function


// first trial
MyClass.prototype.property= property;

// second trial: using bind()
// we have another problem here, property not always a fnction
let propertyBind = property.bind(MyClass)


// third trial: add property while creating the class
let MyClass = class{
  public property = property ;
  public ok =1;
}
```

if `property` is a function, we cannot pass `this` to it as a parameter
because the created class will be provided to a third party that enforces a signature without any parameter

```
let property = (this)=>{ console.log(this.ok); }
``
```

Comment: Where are you actually creating an instance of the class, and invoke `.property()` on it?

Comment: Don't use dynamic classes. Use dynamic objects.

Comment: later, `new myClass = MyClass()`

Comment: I want to extend a base class @Bergi

Comment: Where does a base class come into this? Why do you need to create the property "on the fly" (and what does that even mean to you)? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: I just want to extend the base class to change the value of `property`, it can be of any type, but it may need to access other class properties using `this` as mentioned in the issue's description 

I want to create it on the fly because I want to implement a function that received the value of `property` and then create a class using this value.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to show us that base class as well. Also you haven't really implemented a function that creates a class anywhere. It would help if you could add some usage examples of you want to call this function.

Comment: the base class: `class BaseClass { public property: any;  public ok: any;}` and this is the function `function createClass(property: any){ return class extends BaseClass{ public prperty = property;}`  usage: `let prop = function(){ console.log(this) }; createClass(prop):`

Comment: in the above example usage, I want `this` to refer to the class instead of the function itself

Comment: When you do `const PropClass = createClass(prop); const instance = new PropClass(); instance.property();`, the `this` keyword in `prop` will refer to the instance, not to the class nor to the function. It works as expected.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is this syntax: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function  
`property = function(this: MyClass) { this.ok }`

Comment: but I want to return the created class, not an instance of it

Comment: No, @Jean-Alphonse. the property signature doesn't receive any parameter, as the created class will be provided to a third party that doesn't provide any argument to `property`. also `property` itself may be of any type other than a function

Comment: @Sheldeeb `createClass` *does* return the created class, not an instance. But `.property()` needs to be invoked on an instance, as `.ok` also is an instance property - am I missing something?

Comment: `(this)=>{ console.log(this.ok); }` is a syntax error, and an arrow function doesn't even do what you want.

Comment: what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Sheldeeb `this` is not a valid identifier for a parameter, and due to how arrow functions work you cannot call it so that `this` inside the body refers to the class instance.

Comment: this is just an example, you can use any name you want. however, this example is just to say that I don't want this approach, i.e: passing the class into the function

Comment: @Sheldeeb What do you mean by "*passing the class into the function*"? No classes are passed around anywhere.

Comment: something like this: `let property = (_this)=>{ console.log(_this.ok); }` and in the class `constructor(){ addProperty(this): }`

Comment: @Sheldeeb But that's now what is happening in the code of any of the comments and answers? They use functions with a `this` context, not a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
class BaseClass {
  public property: unknown;
  public ok = 1;
}

function addProperty<Base extends new (...args: any) => any, T>(
  baseClass: Base,
  property: T extends Function ? (this: InstanceType<Base>) => void : T
) {
  return class extends baseClass {
    public property = property;
  };
}

const MyClass1 = addProperty(BaseClass, "hello");
const myClass1 = new MyClass1();
console.log(myClass1.property); // "hello"

const MyClass2 = addProperty(BaseClass, function () {
  // here `this` has type BaseClass
  this.ok++;
});
const myClass2 = new MyClass2();
myClass2.property();
console.log(myClass2.ok); // 2
```

Comment: looks great, I want to implement the following signature: `function createClass(property:any){ return class extends BaseClass{ protected property = property)`

Comment: also, I want `property` to be just a function or of any type, not created by calling external functions